# How to display Products by Category search?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can one display all products of a category, when using the search input field?

e.g. Search field: "yoghurt" --> displays all products from the category yoghurt.

Comment: Why the heck would anyone downgrade this question? There is no similar question. It's straight, consice and tags are attached. Just non-sense! If you don't want to help, then don't, but stop provoke people in need for hints and tips.

Comment: They should really give reason for down vote,as sometimes it would help people to understand why it has been done so that they can avoid it in future. Even i cannot understand the reason for your downvote. Anyway In my prestashop I choose category e.g.- yogurt from the Navigation menu itself and it shows all products of that category so is there any reason why you would want to do that? I mean have you not kept categories in the Menu List?

Comment: Hi @Shrilekha, I would want to do that because, I have products that that would not be know by product name rather then by category name. Guests only care about the category. The category is a state license for what they want licensed products for.

Answer (score 2):

I override the Search class and the find method in this way:

as you can see i added a param in find method ($filterCats) this is an array with the id of the categories you want filter, then implode the array and use the string in query.

```
    public static function find($id_lang, $expr, $page_number = 1, $page_size = 1, $order_by = 'position',
    $order_way = 'desc', $ajax = false, $use_cookie = true, Context $context = null, $filterCats)
{

    $activeFilterString = implode($filterCats, ',');


    if (!$context)
        $context = Context::getContext();
    $db = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_);


    if ($page_number < 1) $page_number = 1;
    if ($page_size < 1) $page_size = 1;

    if (!Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || !Validate::isOrderWay($order_way))
        return false;

    $intersect_array = array();
    $score_array = array();
    $words = explode(' ', Search::sanitize($expr, $id_lang, false, $context->language->iso_code));

    foreach ($words as $key => $word)
        if (!empty($word) && strlen($word) >= (int)Configuration::get('PS_SEARCH_MINWORDLEN'))
        {
            $word = str_replace('%', '\\%', $word);
            $word = str_replace('_', '\\_', $word);
            $intersect_array[] = 'SELECT si.id_product
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'search_word sw
                LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'search_index si ON sw.id_word = si.id_word
                WHERE sw.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                    AND sw.id_shop = '.$context->shop->id.'
                    AND sw.word LIKE
                '.($word[0] == '-'
                    ? ' \''.pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 1, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)).'%\''
                    : '\''.pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 0, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)).'%\''
                );

            if ($word[0] != '-')
                $score_array[] = 'sw.word LIKE \''.pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 0, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)).'%\'';
        }
        else
            unset($words[$key]);

    if (!count($words))
        return ($ajax ? array() : array('total' => 0, 'result' => array()));

    $score = '';
    if (count($score_array))
        $score = ',(
            SELECT SUM(weight)
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'search_word sw
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'search_index si ON sw.id_word = si.id_word
            WHERE sw.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                AND sw.id_shop = '.$context->shop->id.'
                AND si.id_product = p.id_product
                AND ('.implode(' OR ', $score_array).')
        ) position';

    $sql_groups = '';
    if (Group::isFeatureActive())
    {
        $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
        $sql_groups = 'AND cg.`id_group` '.(count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '= 1');
    }

    if (count($fitersArray) == 0){

        $results = $db->executeS('
        SELECT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? 'INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`' : '').'
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p', false).'
        WHERE c.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search")
        AND product_shop.indexed = 1
        '.$sql_groups);

    } else if (count($fitersArray) > 0) {

        $results = $db->executeS('
        SELECT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? 'INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`' : '').'
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p', false).'
        WHERE c.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search")
        AND c.`id_category` IN (' . $activeFilterString .')
        AND product_shop.indexed = 1
        '.$sql_groups);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. In what file did you add this? I thought it belongs to the blocksearch module, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi, you can find this method in classes/Search.php